# rough estimate time it takes to do string comparisons Python

Tags: python, time

I have a string, call it *paragraph* that contains about  50-100 words separated by spaces.
  I have an array of 5500 strings all about 3-5 characters long.
    What I want to do is check each word in *paragraph* and see if any of the words are also contained in my array of 5500 strings.

does anyone have a rough estimate of the time it would take to do a once-over in Python?
   i want to check each word in the paragraph against the array

I will probably end up writing the code anyway as my guess is it won't take too long to process.

If this question is too lazy... how does one go about finding computation time for Python in a simple string example like this?

Comment: If you write the code correctly it will take a fraction of the time you spent writing this question.

Comment: the fastest way to do that is probably set(paragraph.split()).intersect(words) with words being a set too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert your array of 5500 strings to a set and just use a set intersection.

```
>>> paragraph = "five hundred to one hundred words separated by spaces"
>>> array_of_strings = set(['hundred', 'spaces', ])  # make a set..

>>> print set(paragraph.split()).intersection(array_of_strings)
set(['hundred', 'spaces'])
```

Here's how you time it.

Read about the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module. Here's another tutorial: http://diveintopython.net/performance_tuning/timeit.html

```
import timeit
s = """paragraph = "five hundred to one hundred words separated by spaces"
array_of_strings = set(['hundred', 'spaces', ])  # make a set..

set(paragraph.split()).intersection(array_of_strings)
"""
t = timeit.Timer(stmt=s)
print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
```

Comment: i like this though nobody has given me a time estimate... is that because it depends on what your machine/local settings are?

Comment: This is way better than what I was going to say. You might want to `strip()` punctuation out of the words in paragraph though. Oh, and normalize case.

Comment: set intersections are lightning fast. I'll update my answer to reflect the `timeit` module

Comment: @Timtam yes the actual time spent processing is going to be machine dependent.  However you can use something like Big-O notation if that is something you are more careful with.  In Big-O time it would take roughly O(n) or linear time to check each word in your paragraph against a set.

Answer (score 1):

If you use list, sort it first and use binary search.

But it would be probably better to use a dictionary;)

```
import time

def timeo(fun, n=1000): 
    def void(  ): pass 
    start = time.clock(  ) 
    for i in range(n): void(  ) 
    stend = time.clock(  ) 
    overhead = stend - start 
    start = time.clock(  ) 
    for i in range(n): fun(  ) 
    stend = time.clock(  ) 
    fulltime = stend-start 
    return fun.__name__, fulltime-overhead 

for f in solution1, solution2, solution3:
    print "%s: %.2f" % timeo(f)
```